NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for CookieService: (?, ?, ?)
I have an Angular application, using Angular 16, in standalone mode.
I want to use the service from ngx-cookie. So I declared it in "app.config.ts":
...
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [                                                                                                                                                           
provideRouter(routes),                                                                                                                                                                               
CookieService,                     
...
}

Only I have the following error :
NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for CookieService: (?, ?, ?)
In package.json, I have :
"ngx-cookie": "5.0.0",
Any idea?
Thanks.

I've found the solution.
In the "app.config.ts" file, I write:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    { provide: CookieService, useValue: cookieServiceFactory }
  ]
};


I got the same error while using Angular16, ngx-cookie-service.
I don't know why, but I was able to solve it by changing the version of ngx-cookie-service from 2.4.0 to 16.0.0.

As I am using Angular 18, I had to use 18.0.0. Seems they aligned versioning with Angular.
